# Getting null pointer exception when returning string array. In main method returned array is not getting copied to another array i.e. String[] as

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DAOImpl implements DAO
{
    String xs[];
    public String[] readRecord()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("insurance.db"));
            BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


            List<String> al1= new ArrayList<String>();
            String next;
            while((next=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                al1.add(next);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter record number to read:");
        int x=Integer.parseInt(br1.readLine());

        String stream=(al1.get(x-1));

        String[] xs=stream.split(":");
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xs;          
    }
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        DAOImpl d=new DAOImpl();

        String as[]=d.readRecord();
        //here compiler saying nullpointerexcdeption

        for(int v=0;v<as.length;v++)
        {
            System.out.println(as[v]);
        }
    }
}
```

I think problem is with declaring object and then calling readRecord(). The main problem is with array which i returned to method readRecord(). When i am making object and calling readRecord() which will return all the data in String[] as. But its not doing that compiler giving nullPointerException.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger and check the values of the variables?

Comment: You are not closing the BufferedReader correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] xs=stream.split(":");
```

Remove the type on this, i.e.

```
xs=stream.split(":");
```

When you include the type declaration you're creating a new variable with the same name that's local to the try block, not assigning to the class-level field.  This is referred to as "shadowing".

Comment: @Hitman: and what about the NullPointerException like you stated?

Comment: that NPE was correct. Hitman uses the wrong xs variable which was not initiated...

Answer (score 1):

the `String[] xs` variable to which you assign is declared locally in the `try` block and is hiding the one which is declared as class field witch remains null. remove the type declaration `String[]` in the `split` line.